# C# Open Microsoft Edge and reuse the window

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-edge

```cs
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a URL");
    string strURL = Console.ReadLine();
    Process pWeb = new Process();
    pWeb.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    pWeb.StartInfo.FileName = "microsoft-edge:"+ strURL;
    pWeb.Start();
}
```

With this code, when you enter the first URL (http://www.yahoo.com as an example) it will open Edge to Yahoo, it will ask again for a URL and if you type a different one (http://www.stackoverflow.com as an example) it will open a second tab in Edge to StackOverflow.

What I want to do is for it to overwrite the existing site that was pulled up.  I don't want it to open a second tab, I want it to navigate from Yahoo to StackOverflow.

Is there any way to make that work?

Comment: Lookup WebDriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;

Console.WriteLine("Enter a URL");
string strURL0 = Console.ReadLine();
var driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.Url = "https://" + strURL0;

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a URL");
    string strURL = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        driver.Url = "https://" + strURL;
    }
    catch { }
}
```